# Why does resharper not open a file when I click Ctrl+Shift+N?

Tags: resharper

For some reason VS2010 seems to intercept it and want to create a new project.
How do I get round this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want Ctrl-Shift-N to launch the new project dialog then you can remove that keyboard shortcut by going Tools->Options->Environment->Keyboard

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you may need to reapply the ReSharper keyboard scheme.

(Note that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> is the R# keystroke for Go to File only in the (older) 'IntelliJ IDEA' keyboard scheme)

In `ReSharper | Options | Environment | Visual Studio Integration`, select the 'ReSharper 2.x or IntelliJ IDEA`radio button, then click`Apply Scheme`.